# How do I use images from the public directory in my vue app(not the assets folder)?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

If I include images from the assets folder(in src besides App.vue) it will build and run but then not work when changing it with javascript.Eg.:

```css
background-image: url('../assets/img/bg_b.png');
// If I than change it with javascript it doesn't work
background-image: url('../assets/img/bg_w.png');
// I then need to use it like this
background-image: url('/img/bg_w.png');
```

I want to use images from my public folder in vue so the line is the same in javascript and vue. How do I make using an image look the same in vue and browser:

```css
background-image: url('/img/bg_w.png');
```

Answer (score 0):

If the image URL is `/img/bg_w.png`, the file should be in:

```
public/img/bg_w.png
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-img-from-public?file=src%2FApp.vue)